# Redirect To Offline Page

Tags: javascript, service-worker, create-react-app, workbox

I have a `React` app created by using `create-react-app`. By default, this tool creates a `serviceWorker.js` file for us and I am using this to register a `service-worker`. Furthermore, the documents suggest using google's `workbox wizard` to create a `service-worker.js` used to manage my website for offline purposes. The goal is for me to store an `offline.html` page in the browsers cache and whenever there is no online connection, render the cached `offline.html` page.

I am successful in storing the `offline.html` in cache as you can see below. [image]

However, I am having trouble grabbing this file and rendering it whenever there isn't a connection. Here is my code:

`workbox-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "build-development/",
  "globPatterns": [
    ".offline/*.html",
    "external/logo_purple.png"
  ],
  "swDest": "build-development/sw.js",
  "swSrc": "src/sw.js",
  "injectionPointRegexp": /(const precacheManifest = )\[\](;)/
};
```

`sw.js (created by running the workbox config)`:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.1.0/workbox-sw.js");

const precacheManifest = [];

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(precacheManifest);

const dataCacheConfig = {
  cacheName: 'offline'
};

workbox.routing.registerRoute("http://localhost:4000/.offline/offline.html", workbox.strategies.cacheFirst(dataCacheConfig), 'GET');
```

Any ideas?